# Disk problem for Mac, partition unaccessible and type shown as FFFFFFFFF

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, startup

Having a bit of difficulty with my Mac. Was trying to partition to install a Linux mint partition and it all fell apart. On disk utility the command diskutil list shows what is shown in the image, and if I try to use gpt remove after unmounting I get the error resource busy and cannot go forward. The FFFFF partition is the one I am unable to boot in, and is a standard Mac OS Monterey partition. Any ideas on how to solve this? thank you all for your time.

[image]

Comment: Please search before posting - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=FFFFFFFF

Comment: The output you posted is complete gibberish. You have deleted and inserted characters to the point where I can not decipher what is posted. Try pasting the exact output to your question. Don't worry about the formatting. Someone will take care of cleaning up your post.

Comment: Changed the post by adding a picture, hope it can be of help!

Comment: Where are you booted from when entering the `gpt` command? If you are boot from somewhere on `disk0`, then you probably would get an error message. Can you possible boot to an USB flash drive [live session](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) of Linux Mint? If you can, then I think you can enter commands in a Linux Mint terminal window which will fix your Mac.

Comment: I can use a live distro of Linux mint. I am booted in disk recovery mode, using the terminal